# Validate a gsheet/excel relative range string using js regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a range using javascript
Any range that has $ symbol must say invalid
Any range string that has symbols other than : must say invalid
Accpetable characters are capital or small alphabets and 0-9 numbers

Some of the expected results

```
A0  // invalid range begins with 1 
ZZ12    // valid  
ZZ12:   // invalid incorrectly terminated 
:A11    // invalid incorrectly started 
:1  // invalid incorrectly started 
:A  // invalid incorrectly started 
A1  // valid  
B1  // valid  
A2  // valid  
C:F // valid  
A10:B10 // valid  
A:B10   // valid  
A10:B   // valid  
A:B // valid  
10:10   // valid  
AA1 // valid  
AAA1    // valid  
B9:B10  // valid  
A   // invalid incomplete range string 
1   // invalid incomplete range string 
B   // invalid incomplete range string 
20  // invalid only a number not allowed 
@   // invalid symbols not allowed 
##  // invalid symbols not allowed
```

I have tried with

```js
["A0","ZZ12","ZZ12:",":A11",":1",":A","A1","B1","A2","C:F","A10:B10","A:B10","A10:B","A:B","10:10","AA1","AAA1","B9:B10","A","1","B","20","@","##"]
.map(zz=>{return zz + "--->" + /^[A-Z]?[0-9]?:[A-Z]?[0-9]?$/.test(zz)})
```

Comment: There is no good way in regex to mark something like `Z9:A1` as invalid due to the start of the range being greater than the end.

Comment: No problem, let me exclude them, I updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution should address all your requirements, also for non-zero numbers:

```js
const regex = /^(?:[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*|[A-Z]+(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?:[A-Z]+(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?|[1-9][0-9]*:[1-9][0-9]*)$/;

["A0","ZZ12","ZZ12:",":A11",":1",":A","A1","B1","A2","C:F","A10:B10","A:B10","A10:B","A:B","10:10","1:999","0:1","AA1","AAA1","B9:B10","A","1","B","20","@","##"
].map(str => {
  //let valid = regex.test(str);
  let valid = str.match(regex);
  console.log(str, '==>', valid ? 'ok' : 'invalid');
});
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^(?:` -- start of string and non-capture group start

  - `[A-Z]+[1-9][0-9]*` -- 1+ letters, number starting from 1
- `|` -- logical or

  - `[A-Z]+(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?:[A-Z]+(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?` -- 1+ letters, optional number starting from 1, `:`, 1+ letters, optional number starting from 1
- `|` -- logical or

  - `[1-9][0-9]*:[1-9][0-9]*` -- 1+ letters, number starting from 1, `:`, 1+ letters, number starting from 1
- `)$` -- end of non-capture group and string

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following regex and JS code. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QeqWya/1) for used regex.

```js
const regex = /^(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d*:[a-zA-Z]+\d*|[a-zA-Z]+[1-9]+\d*|\d+:\d+)$/;

[
"A0",
"ZZ12",
"ZZ12:",
":A11",
":1",
":A",
"A1",
"B1",
"A2",
"C:F",
"A10:B10",
"A:B10",
"A10:B",
"A:B",
"10:10",
"AA1",
"AAA1",
"B9:B10",
"A",
"1",
"B",
"20",
"@",
"##",
"$"
].forEach(element => 
    console.log(`${element} ----> ${regex.test(element)}`)
);
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above used regex.

```
^                    ##Checking from starting of value here.
(?:                  ##Starting one and only non-capturing group here.
  [a-zA-Z]+\d*:      ##matching 1 or more alphabets followed by 0 or more digits followed by colon.
  [a-zA-Z]+\d*       ##matching 1 or more alphabets followed by 0 or more digits here.
  |                  ##Putting OR condition here.
  [a-zA-Z]+[1-9]+\d* ##Matching 1 or more alphabets followed by 1 or more digits.
  |                  ##Putting OR condition here.
  \d+:\d+            ##Matching 1 or more digits followed by colon followed by 1 or more digits.
)$                   ##Closing non-capturing group at the end of the value here.
```

Comment: Your `[1-9]+` pattern does not allow number 10, 100, 101, 110 etc. , better use `[1-9]\d*`. Also, no need for `(?![$])` since the rest of the pattern does not allow it anyway

Comment: @PeterThoeny, Thank you for letting know, I have edited my answer now.

Comment: You can simplify your pattern to `^(?:[a-z]+\d*:[a-z]+\d*|[a-z]+[1-9]+\d*|\d+:\d+)$` and also use `/i` for a case insensitive match. You can omit a non capturing group here `(?:[a-zA-Z]+\d*)` because the grouping by itself like this has no extra purpose. This part is redundant `(?![$])` because the pattern already starts with either a char a-z or a digit :-) See https://regex101.com/r/QeqWya/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Thank you sir edited my solution as per your nice suggestion, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^([A-Za-z])\1*(?:[1-9]\d*)*:([A-Za-z])\2*(?:[1-9]\d*)*$|^(?:([A-Za-z])\3*|[1-9]\d*:)[1-9]\d*$
```

*Explanation:*

> First part `^([A-Za-z])\1*(?:[1-9]\d*)*:([A-Za-z])\2*(?:[1-9]\d*)*$` to match things like `C:F`, `A10:B10`, `A:B10`, `A10:B`, `A:B` and `B9:B10`.

- `^` start of the line/string.
- `([A-Za-z])` Group1: `[A-Za-z]` one letter captured by the first group, and the value inside the first capturing group can be accessed by `\1`.
- `\1*`, `\1` the value inside the first capturing group, `*` match zero or more of the value inside the first capturing group, for example if the value is `A`, then things like `AAA` will be matched.
- `(?:[1-9]\d*)*` non-capturing group, `[1-9]` one digit from `1` to `9`, followed by `\d*` zero or more digits from `0` to `9`, and that group will be repeated between zero or more times.
- `:` a literal colon `:`.
- `([A-Za-z])` Group2:`[A-Za-z]` the same as before with Group1, but now we can access the value inside the second capturing group by `\2`.
- `\2*` the same as before with `\1*`, but now the value is the one inside the second capturing group.
- `(?:[1-9]\d*)*` the same as before.
- `$` the end of the line/string.
- `|` the alternation operator it is like `Boolean OR`, to match other cases.

> Second part `^(?:([A-Za-z])\3*|[1-9]\d*:)[1-9]\d*$` to match things like `A1`, `B1`, `A2` and `10:10`.

- `^` the start of the line/string.
- `(?:([A-Za-z])\3*|[1-9]\d*:)` non-capturing group contains:

  - `([A-Za-z])` Group3:`[A-Za-z]` the same as before with Group1 and Group2, but now we can access the value inside the third capturing group by `\3`.
  - `\3*` the same as before with `\1*` and `\2*`, but now the value is the one inside the third capturing group.
  - `|` the alternation operator it is like `Boolean OR`, to match other cases.
  - `[1-9]\d*:` one digit from `1` to `9`, followed by zero or more digits from `0` to `9`, followed by a literal `:`.
- `[1-9]\d*` one digit from `1` to `9`, followed by zero or more digits from `0` to `9`.
- `$` the end of the line/string.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BfX6Ap/1)

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird for reminding me, that is what I really do, but for this specific one somehow I forgot it, because I answer a question then try to edit it multiple times and add explanation but this time I forgot this one.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I added the explanation, thanks again  for reminding me.